# How do you heatmap in tavleau a list of numbers based on another column data

Tags: tableau-api

I have data from 48 countries. I am trying to visualize it on a map. I want to display half the countries in 1 color and the other half in another color. This segmentation is based on another column which has string value 'yes' or 'no'. I want to do it on tableau

```
Country   data      OFF
------------------------
US        100,000   yes
IN        200,000   yes
BR        300,000   no
MX        150,000   no
```

I want to plot US, IN in Blue and BR, MX in green. The shades of green and blue are dependent on the values of data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to drag the OFF field to Color in the sheet? This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can put either the measure data on the color shelf to color by value, or the dimension OFF on the color shelf to color by OFF -- i.e. to use color to encode a single field's value.

If you want to color by two dimension fields, you can get the shading effect you mention by putting both on the color shelf -- using the shift key to add the second one if it's not in a hierarchy with the first one.

If you want to color by both a dimension and a measure (as in your case), you have to go to a little more effort -- assuming its worth it. You can make a calculated field that uses both fields to map into a category (say returning a string like "off yes, data high" or "off yes, data mid") and then edit the colors to map them as you like.